# Mi código inserta el primer registro en la base, pero si uno sigue ingresando información no guarda más

Tags: php, mysql, registro

El código, al digitarlo y probarlo por primera vez, me guarda correctamente la información, sin embargo, al guardar un segundo registro ya no guarda nada, no muestra ningún error ni nada.

No solo me pasa con este archivo, me pasa igual al guardar datos de clientes en otro proyecto, no sé si es problema de código o algún permiso de mysql.

Este es el código:

```
<?php 
include_once 'database.php';

    if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
    {

      $id_placa=$_POST['id_placa'];
       $forma_pago=$_POST['forma_pago'];
        $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];

           if(!empty($id_placa) && !empty($forma_pago) && !empty($fecha))
           {
               $consulta_insert=$con->prepare('INSERT INTO ordenes_trabajo(id_orden;id_placa,forma_pago,fecha) VALUES(:id_orden,:id_placa,:forma_pago,:fecha)');
               $consulta_insert->execute(array(

               ':id_placa' =>$id_placa,
               ':forma_pago' =>$forma_pago,
               ':fecha' =>$fecha,
                           ));

        header('Location: charts.php');
     }else{
         echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
     }
}else{
    echo ".";  
}

?>
```

Código del formulario, lo curioso es que no guarda la información sin embargo el id_orden autoincrementable de mi tabla si avanza secuencia, entonces no se en donde pueda estar el error

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="id_placa" placeholder="Placa" class="input__text">


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="forma_pago" placeholder="forma de pago" class="input__text">


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" class="input__text">
        </div>
        <div class="btn__group">
            <a href="charts.php" class="btn btn__danger">Cancelar</a>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar" class="btn btn__primary">
        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código del formulario. Si estás usando AJAX, también agrégalo.

Comment: ya lo agregue!.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene toda la pinta de ser porque estás enviando en el POST el `id_orden` que probablemente sea la clave principal de la tabla `ordenes_trabajo`. De ahí que únicamente te deje introducir el primero.

Lo resuelves eliminando ese campo del `INSERT` y dejando que se vayan asignando IDs con un autonumérico. Ya sabes, con:

```
ALTER TABLE ordenes_trabajo
 CHANGE id_orden id_orden INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Por favor, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para mejorar la respuesta

Comment: Hola, Gracias por contestar, le quite el campo que me dices pero igual pasa, no guarda la información, pero curiosamente si incrementa el id_orden en mi tabla de mysql

Comment: @SandraNaranjoPáez Acabo de ver un `;` en el `INSERT` del `prepare()`. ¿Has comprobado eso?